# iTunes - CLI AppleMobileBackup

Tags: itunes, command-line

I'm trying to use command line to backup my device with iTunes.

I found this script:
https://nerd.one/how-to-automate-daily-encrypted-iphone-backups-in-itunes/

issue: that it can't do multiple devices.

found this:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98066?answerId=653097022#653097022

But doesn't seem to work.

does anyone know how to get it work with iTunes?

Comment: note that your first link is from 2016 and that iTunes (in current versions of macOS) no longer manages iOS devices, *Finder* does. Also are you trying to do this on a Windows PC (as per the 2nd link) or on macOS?

Comment: Yes, the macOS I'm using runs iTunes already have a solution for finder sync.